# Why can't I select a different language for a form in WFFM?

Tags: wffm

I have Sitecore 7.5 with Webforms for Marketers 2.5.  I want to create a form in the French language.  However I can't seem to select French as a language.  When I open up the form designer there is a button and a dropdown to select a language other than English.  However when I click on it nothing happens.  I have a number of languages installed in this Sitecore instances.  I have EN, de-DE, es-ES, fr-FR and zh-CN.  I click on the button or the dropdown to select a language and literally nothing happens.  No error message or anything.  But also no way to select a different language for the form.  Am I doing something wrong?  Below is a screen shot of the button/dropdown in the form designer.

[image]

Comment: Can you check chrome's network tab to see what request goes out when this is clicked?

Comment: Nothing happens in the Chrome network tab when I click that button.

Comment: do you have any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: I found the following JS error: Uncaught ReferenceError - scRect is not defined. I see now that this is a known error and was fixed in a subsequent WFFM update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have Sitecore 7.5 with WFFM module installed but this is listed as known bug in [Sitecore knowledge base site](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/616431).

It was fixed in WFFM 8.0 Update-2 as mentioned in the link above.

> **[Fixed in WFFM 8.0 Update-2]** It is not possible to translate form in Form Designer. 'Language' dropdown doesn't show languages (24964).